# Can't change default session

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux, mate-desktop

I have Kali-64bit installed in Virtual Box, and I'm simply trying to set the MATE environment as my default for when I reboot/shutdown and log in afterwards.

I've tried

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

and choosing mate-session (be it auto/manual mode) but I still get signed into the default GNOME environment.

Yet when I run update-alternatives command again, MATE is still selected and hasn't reverted back to GNOME.

[image: update-alternatives output]

This should be such a minute command that I've ran on two other Kali installations and it worked flawlessly, yet on my Vbox installations, the update-alternatives just wouldn't stick.

Comment: If that solution does not apply, another solution would be to install the [MATE version of Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/downloads)

Comment: It finally worked via removing the gnome sessions from the usr/share/xsessions directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finally worked thanks to kemotep's comment citing another question.

What I did was navigate to /usr/share/xsessions and remove everything gnome-related.

Weirdly enough, using

```
# update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

*or*

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/bin/mate-session 60
```

didn't solve my issue when either should have.